# Pantalla en blanco sin error al hacer un update con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Buen dia, tengo el error que cuando se ejecuta el archivo update.php se queda en blanco, sin ningun error, actualiza el registro, pero no me ejecuta el script que hacer el header a la pantalla principal. ¿que podra ser? les comparto mi codigo:

editar.php:

```
<?php
$idpte = $_GET["id"];
<form action="update.php" method="post">
<!-- Todo el codigo html -->
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $idpte; ?>">
</form>
?>
```

update.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connection.php");

$nivel_academico = empty($_POST["nivel_academico"]) ? "" : ($_POST["nivel_academico"]);
$ocupacion = empty($_POST["ocupacion"]) ? "" : ($_POST["ocupacion"]);
$estado_civil = empty($_POST["estado_civil"]) ? "" : ($_POST["estado_civil"]);
$esposo = empty($_POST["esposo"]) ? "" : ($_POST["esposo"]);
$dui = empty($_POST["dui"]) ? "" : ($_POST["dui"]);
$nit = empty($_POST["nit"]) ? "" : ($_POST["nit"]);
$doc_matrimonio = empty($_POST["doc_matrimonio"]) ? "" : ($_POST["doc_matrimonio"]);
$persona_cobra = empty($_POST["persona_cobra"]) ? "" : ($_POST["persona_cobra"]);
$beneficiario_defuncion = empty($_POST["beneficiario_defuncion"]) ? "" : ($_POST["beneficiario_defuncion"]);
$direccion = empty($_POST["direccion"]) ? "" : ($_POST["direccion"]);
$nombre_referencia = empty($_POST["nombre_referencia"]) ? "" : ($_POST["nombre_referencia"]);
$hijos_si = empty($_POST["hijos_si"]) ? "" : ($_POST["hijos_si"]);
$numero_hijos = empty($_POST["numero_hijos"]) ? "" : ($_POST["numero_hijos"]);
$nombre_hijo_uno = empty($_POST["nombre_hijo_uno"]) ? "" : ($_POST["nombre_hijo_uno"]);
$edad_hijo_uno = empty($_POST["edad_hijo_uno"]) ? "" : ($_POST["edad_hijo_uno"]);
$nivel_academico_uno = empty($_POST["nivel_academico_uno"]) ? "" : ($_POST["nivel_academico_uno"]);
$nombre_hijo_dos = empty($_POST["nombre_hijo_dos"]) ? "" : ($_POST["nombre_hijo_dos"]);
$edad_hijo_dos = empty($_POST["edad_hijo_dos"]) ? "" : ($_POST["edad_hijo_dos"]);
$nivel_academico_dos = empty($_POST["nivel_academico_dos"]) ? "" : ($_POST["nivel_academico_dos"]);
$nombre_hijo_tres = empty($_POST["nombre_hijo_tres"]) ? "" : ($_POST["nombre_hijo_tres"]);
$edad_hijo_tres = empty($_POST["edad_hijo_tres"]) ? "" : ($_POST["edad_hijo_tres"]);
$nivel_academico_tres = empty($_POST["nivel_academico_tres"]) ? "" : ($_POST["nivel_academico_tres"]);
$ingresos_familiares = empty($_POST["ingresos_familiares"]) ? "" : ($_POST["ingresos_familiares"]);
$fuente_ing = empty($_POST["fuente_ing"]) ? "" : ($_POST["fuente_ing"]);
$depende_economica = empty($_POST["depende_economica"]) ? "" : ($_POST["depende_economica"]);
$asegurado = empty($_POST["asegurado"]) ? "" : ($_POST["asegurado"]);
$area_cotizacion = empty($_POST["area_cotizacion"]) ? "" : ($_POST["area_cotizacion"]);
$enfermedad = empty($_POST["enfermedad"]) ? "" : ($_POST["enfermedad"]);
$enfermedades = empty($_POST["enfermedades"]) ? "" : ($_POST["enfermedades"]);
$medicamentos = empty($_POST["medicamentos"]) ? "" : ($_POST["medicamentos"]);
$tipo_medicamento = empty($_POST["tipo_medicamento"]) ? "" : ($_POST["tipo_medicamento"]);
$acceso_unidades = empty($_POST["acceso_unidades"]) ? "" : ($_POST["nivel_academico"]);
$establecimiento_salud = empty($_POST["establecimiento_salud"]) ? "" : ($_POST["establecimiento_salud"]);
$discapacidad = empty($_POST["discapacidad"]) ? "" : ($_POST["discapacidad"]);
$tipo_discapacidad = empty($_POST["tipo_discapacidad"]) ? "" : ($_POST["tipo_discapacidad"]);
$trastornos = empty($_POST["trastornos"]) ? "" : ($_POST["trastornos"]);
$tipo_trastornos = empty($_POST["tipo_trastornos"]) ? "" : ($_POST["tipo_trastornos"]);
$formacion = empty($_POST["formacion"]) ? "" : ($_POST["formacion"]);
$areas = empty($_POST["areas"]) ? "" : ($_POST["areas"]);
$beca = empty($_POST["beca"]) ? "" : ($_POST["beca"]);
$edad_hijo = empty($_POST["edad_hijo"]) ? "" : ($_POST["edad_hijo"]);
$edu_basica = empty($_POST["edu_basica"]) ? "" : ($_POST["edu_basica"]);
$retornado = empty($_POST["retornado"]) ? "" : ($_POST["retornado"]);
$formacion_integral = empty($_POST["formacion_integral"]) ? "" : ($_POST["formacion_integral"]);
$obstaculos_estudios = empty($_POST["obstaculos_estudios"]) ? "" : ($_POST["obstaculos_estudios"]);
$consentimiento = empty($_POST["consentimiento"]) ? "" : ($_POST["consentimiento"]);
$obstaculos_becados = empty($_POST["obstaculos_becados"]) ? "" : ($_POST["obstaculos_becados"]);
$medios_comunicacion = empty($_POST["medios_comunicacion"]) ? "" : ($_POST["medios_comunicacion"]);
$vivienda_propia = empty($_POST["vivienda_propia"]) ? "" : ($_POST["vivienda_propia"]);
$alquila = empty($_POST["alquila"]) ? "" : ($_POST["alquila"]);
$inmueble = empty($_POST["inmueble"]) ? "" : ($_POST["inmueble"]);
$tipo_inmueble = empty($_POST["tipo_inmueble"]) ? "" : ($_POST["tipo_inmueble"]);
$cuantas_propiedades = empty($_POST["cuantas_propiedades"]) ? "" : ($_POST["cuantas_propiedades"]);
$beneficio_cons = empty($_POST["beneficio_cons"]) ? "" : ($_POST["beneficio_cons"]);
$trans_tierra = empty($_POST["trans_tierra"]) ? "" : ($_POST["trans_tierra"]);
$cambio_beneficio = empty($_POST["cambio_beneficio"]) ? "" : ($_POST["cambio_beneficio"]);
$riesgos_naturales = empty($_POST["riesgos_naturales"]) ? "" : ($_POST["riesgos_naturales"]);
$residencia = empty($_POST["residencia"]) ? "" : ($_POST["residencia"]);
$tipo_vivienda = empty($_POST["tipo_vivienda"]) ? "" : ($_POST["tipo_vivienda"]);
$servicios = empty($_POST["servicios"]) ? "" : ($_POST["servicios"]);
$que_servicios = empty($_POST["que_servicios"]) ? "" : ($_POST["que_servicios"]);
$negocio = empty($_POST["negocio"]) ? "" : ($_POST["negocio"]);
$act_comerical = empty($_POST["act_comerical"]) ? "" : ($_POST["act_comerical"]);
$parcela = empty($_POST["parcela"]) ? "" : ($_POST["parcela"]);
$departamento_parcela = empty($_POST["departamento_parcela"]) ? "" : ($_POST["departamento_parcela"]);
$municipio_parcela = empty($_POST["municipio_parcela"]) ? "" : ($_POST["municipio_parcela"]);
$parcela_tam = empty($_POST["parcela_tam"]) ? "" : ($_POST["parcela_tam"]);
$quintales = empty($_POST["quintales"]) ? "" : ($_POST["quintales"]);
$siembra = empty($_POST["siembra"]) ? "" : ($_POST["siembra"]);
$paquetes_agricolas = empty($_POST["paquetes_agricolas"]) ? "" : ($_POST["paquetes_agricolas"]);
$inco_agricolas = empty($_POST["inco_agricolas"]) ? "" : ($_POST["inco_agricolas"]);
$padron = empty($_POST["padron"]) ? "" : ($_POST["padron"]);
$idpte = $_POST["id_form"];

$query = "UPDATE encuesta SET nivel_academico = '$nivel_academico', ocupacion = '$ocupacion', estado_civil = '$estado_civil', esposo = '$esposo', dui = '$dui', nit = '$nit', doc_matrimonio = '$doc_matrimonio', persona_cobra = '$persona_cobra', beneficiario_defuncion = '$beneficiario_defuncion', direccion = '$direccion', nombre_referencia = '$nombre_referencia', hijos_si = '$hijos_si', numero_hijos = '$numero_hijos', nombre_hijo_uno = '$nombre_hijo_uno', edad_hijo_uno = '$edad_hijo_uno', nivel_academico_uno = '$nivel_academico_uno', nombre_hijo_dos = '$nombre_hijo_dos', edad_hijo_dos = '$edad_hijo_dos', nivel_academico_dos = '$nivel_academico_dos', nombre_hijo_tres = '$nombre_hijo_tres', edad_hijo_tres = '$edad_hijo_tres', nivel_academico_tres = '$nivel_academico_tres', ingresos_familiares = '$ingresos_familiares', fuente_ing = '$fuente_ing', depende_economica = '$depende_economica', asegurado = '$asegurado', area_cotizacion = '$area_cotizacion', enfermedad = '$enfermedad', enfermedades = '$enfermedades', medicamentos = '$medicamentos', tipo_medicamento = '$tipo_medicamento', acceso_unidades = '$acceso_unidades', establecimiento_salud = '$establecimiento_salud', discapacidad = '$discapacidad', tipo_discapacidad = '$tipo_discapacidad', trastornos = '$trastornos', tipo_trastornos = '$tipo_trastornos', formacion = '$formacion', areas = '$areas', beca = '$beca', edad_hijo = '$edad_hijo', edu_basica = '$edu_basica', retornado = '$retornado', formacion_integral = '$formacion_integral', obstaculos_estudios = '$obstaculos_estudios', consentimiento = '$consentimiento', obstaculos_becados = '$obstaculos_becados', medios_comunicacion = '$medios_comunicacion', vivienda_propia = '$vivienda_propia', alquila = '$alquila', inmueble = '$inmueble', tipo_inmueble = '$tipo_inmueble', cuantas_propiedades = '$cuantas_propiedades', beneficio_cons = '$beneficio_cons', trans_tierra = '$trans_tierra', cambio_beneficio = '$cambio_beneficio', riesgos_naturales = '$riesgos_naturales', residencia = '$residencia', tipo_vivienda = '$tipo_vivienda', servicios = '$servicios', que_servicios = '$que_servicios', negocio = '$negocio', act_comerical = '$act_comerical', parcela = '$parcela', departamento_parcela = '$departamento_parcela', municipio_parcela = '$municipio_parcela', parcela_tam = '$parcela_tam', quintales = '$quintales', siembra = '$siembra', paquetes_agricolas = '$paquetes_agricolas', inco_agricolas = '$inco_agricolas', padron = '$padron' WHERE id_enc = '$idpte'";
if(mysqli_error($link)) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    exit();
}
$success = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$id = mysqli_insert_id($link);

if ($success){
    
    echo "<script>
            alert('Registro actualizado exitosamente.);
                    window.location='dashboard.php?update=true'
                  </script>";
}

/*else{
    header("location: dashboard.php?error=true");   
}*/
elseif(mysqli_error($link)) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    exit();
}
?>
```

La cuestion es que al hacer todo el proceso se queda en el navegador en una pantalla en blanco en la barra de direcciones localhost/sistema/update.php

El registro si se actualiza, pero queda ahi, este codigo nunca lo ejecuta:

```
if ($success){

    echo "<script>
            alert('Registro actualizado exitosamente.);
                    window.location='dashboard.php?update=true'
                  </script>";
}
```

Ayuda por favor!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema de que no muestra el mensaje, ni hace el redirect es porque hace falta el cierre de comilla del string en esta línea:

```
alert('Registro actualizado exitosamente.);
```

Desde la consola de Javascript lo hubieses detectado rapidamente.

Adicional tienes un typo en la línea

```
$acceso_unidades = empty($_POST["acceso_unidades"]) ? "" : ($_POST["nivel_academico"]);
```

---

Así como está debe funcionar bien, pero por la extensa cantidad de entradas del formulario el código queda bastante complejo y redundante, por ende más difícil de mantener, lo que puede provocar errores como el typo anterior.

Todo ese código se podría simplificar a un array con todos los items enviados por el formulario y una función que hace los request por cada uno de los item:

```
function request_value($item) {
    $value = empty($_POST[$item]) ? "" : $_POST[$item];
    return "$item='$value'";
}

$subq_updt = '';
$dbcols = array('nivel_academico', 'ocupacion', 'estado_civil', 'esposo', 'dui', 
'nit', 'doc_matrimonio', 'persona_cobra', 'beneficiario_defuncion' /* ... etc ... */);
$i = 0;
foreach($dbcols as $item) {
    $subq_updt .= (++$i > 1) ? ', ' : '';
    $subq_updt .= request_value($item);
}

$idpte = $_POST["id_form"];
$query = "UPDATE encuesta SET " . $subq_updt . " WHERE id_enc = '$idpte'";
```

Con los `INSERT` podrías hacer algo similar pero que la función devuelva, por ejemplo un `array($item, $value);`
Luego en el `foreach` se arman dos subquerys: `$into .= $array[0]` y `$values .= $array[1]` y al final:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ($into) VALUES ($values);"
```

Incluso hasta el `<form>` html se puede reconstruir con el mismo array.

Finalmente debes tener muy en cuenta la susceptibilidad del código a [Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/80870).

Comment: Muchas gracias @aeportugal